# Can I connect my model to an external app?

Tags: python, django

I've installed a new app thorough pip (it's called django-sitetree).
I want to know if I can connect my models (like Category model) to this app with Foreignkey our something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this `django-sitetree` is the module and you can not connect it with your app model to any `Foreignkey`.

Because you only give model field or model as `Foreignkey`.

Comment: As you know this module makes menus and sub-menus. Is there a way that I can make those menus non-static and somehow make it dynamic?

Comment: I only know the basic of this module, I am not sure about your requirements cz yet I am not used this module.

Comment: I found this link https://django-sitetree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#tree-custom maybe it is helpful for you. :)